# Order on Euclidean space in which a finite poset embeds

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets

Fix positive integers $k$ and $n$.

For which finite posets $(X,\lesssim)$ with $\#X=k$ does there exist an order embedding $\phi\colon(X,\lesssim)\to (\mathbb{R}^n,\le)$, where $\le$ is the standard partial order (product order) on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Are there quantitative bounds on the minimal such $n$ for specific subclasses of these posets?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152239/discussion-on-question-by-abim-order-on-euclidean-space-in-which-a-finite-poset); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

If $(P,\le)$ is a poset, the least $n$ such that $(P,\le)$ embeds into a product of $n$ total orders (or equivalently, such that $\le$ is the intersection of $n$ total orders on $P$) is known as the [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension) of $(P,\le)$. If $P$ is finite, this is equivalent to embedding into the product of $n$ copies of any fixed infinite total order, such as $(\mathbb R,\le)$. Thus, the question is exactly about which posets of size $k$ have dimension at most $n$.

As Sam Hopkins notes in a comment, now banished to the [netherworld](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65404453#65404453), classifying posets of a given dimension is likely very hard. But for some basic bounds, all posets of size $k$ have dimension at most $k$, as $(P,\le)$ embeds to $(\mathcal P(P),\subseteq)\simeq\{0,1\}^k$ via $a\mapsto\{x\in P:x\le a\}$; on the other hand, the Wikipedia article gives an example of a poset of dimension $k/2$.

Comment: I thought links would be harmless, but, if you prefer to have them not in the post, then I apologise for editing them in.  People can surely find the Wikipedia example themselves, but I'll link here to @SamHopkins's [observation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65404453#65404453) about the difficulty of classifying posets of a given dimension.

Comment: Linking to the same Wikipedia article twice is something I certainly find excessive. I didn't notice the comments on the question were meanwhile completely butchered by moderators (it's beyond my understanding what they find objectionable about the thread, which was on the whole quite constructive, and targeted at figuring out the intended question). In that case, I'll put the link back.

Comment: A survey from 1982 by Kelley and Trotter appears at https://trotter.math.gatech.edu/papers/31.pdf. There is also Trotter's book *Combinatorics and Partially Ordered Sets* available from https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Partially-Ordered-Sets-Mathematical/dp/0801869773.

Comment: Thank you. ${}$